# Why kali linux unable to boot on newer kernels?

Tags: linux, boot, kernel

I have updated kali Linux from 2019.4 to 2020.4 and now to 2021.1 but I'm unable to boot from the newly installed kernel(as kernel 5.8 in 2019.4, kernel 5.9 in 2020.4 and kernel 5.10 in 2020.1) and therefore ever since I have been using 5.5.17 kernel image only.

I haven't faced such a problem on upgrading ubuntu

[Here the listed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTzzX.png)

[Currently used kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNVbI.png)

Comment: What does _"I'm unable to boot from the newly installed kernel"_ mean precisely?

Comment: I am on Kali 2021 .1 here with Kernel 5.9.0 .  Working fine. What do you see when you start up, restart?  Can you do Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or F2) to get a text login?

Comment: How are you updating Kali Linux?

Comment: @John it stucked at Started GDM desktop manager before it displays login screen.Also there is no failure message I checked in boot.log,system.log and journalctl -xb

Comment: @harrymc I Followed this https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/updating-kali/

Comment: @John are you using nvidia drivers on 2021.1 for GPU?

Comment: No. Integrated graphics on two machines where I run Kali machines (virtual machines)

Comment: I tried this for changing DM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390076/gdm-display-manager-fails-to-display-login
But it didn't work

Comment: I found out the reason guys, it's due to NVIDIA display drivers after updating to the newer version fixed the problems. As Driver version > 430 only allow the support for kernel 5.9.